# Simpledateformat parse subtracts instead of adding

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to change the time that I get (in CEST/CET) to GMT to store it in my database. BUT when I parse the date in CEST to GMT, instead of subtracting 2, it adds 2 hours!

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()); //My locale is CEST
Date dateOfBooking = formatter.parse(bookedDate + " " + bookedDateTime); //Here the time is 10:09

formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // Timezone I need to store the date in
dateOfBooking = formatter.parse(bookedDate + " " + bookedDateTime); // Here the time is 12:09
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
bookedDateTime = timeFormat.format(dateOfBooking);
```

Can anybody explain why? I've tried setting my local timezone to different ones and it always work the other way, subtracting instead of adding and viceversa.

Comment: "CEST" is not a Locale, it is a time zone. Locale determines the human language used for translating day-of-week and the cultural norms for issues such as commas-versus-period. But Locale is completely separate and unrelated to time zone. Another issue: `CEST` is not really a time zone. A [proper time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) is a continent/region such as `Europe/Paris`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are parsing the date again as GMT. (which, when printed as CEST, or your locale timezone, will add + 2 hours)

What you actually want is to print out the already parsed date as GMT:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()); //My locale is CEST
Date dateOfBooking = formatter.parse(bookedDate + " " + bookedDateTime); //Here the time is 10:09

DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
bookedDateTime = timeFormat.format(dateOfBooking);
System.out.println(bookedDateTime);
```

Basicly you have to set the GMT zone in your timeFormat that you use to create the time string, not the formatter that you use for parsing